# javascript observable error handling

Tags: javascript, observable

I am trying to generate custom error handling when my observable fails instead of getting a big `404` error in my console. However, no matter how many tutorials I read I jsut can't figure out how it works.

my code is as follows:

```
datacontext.graph.getUserProfilePicture('', detailedData.id)
.then(function success(photo) {
    console.log("succesful call" + photo);
})
.catch(function error(err) {
    console.log("error" + err);
});
```

The success statement works, however the fail method doesn't.

Here is the call that I make to the ,icrosoft graph endpoint:

```
function getUserPic(principalName) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var endpoint = config.baseGraphApiUrl + "users/" + principalName + "/photo/$value";
            $http.get(endpoint, { responseType: 'blob' }).then(function (result) {
                var file = new Blob([result.data], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                deferred.resolve(fileURL);
            }, function (data) {
                console.log(error);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

on success it returns:
succesful call blob:http://localhost:8480/7da29a36-d13d-440f-8207-75f1cde58fcf

on failure it returns: 
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/63c31121-cd15-4f48-ba43-8dea613f19cd/photo/$value 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This does not look like an observable, but a promise.

Comment: It either succeeds or fails!

Comment: .catch(function(err){console.log(err}) replace that line like this

Comment: ah that's probably the mistake i made, @Kumar, i tried that but no success. so I guess my last resort is a try {} catch {} block

Comment: Try adding a second argument of `function(reason)` to your `.then` call instead of `catch`.

Comment: @RodneyWormsbecher `datacontext.graph.getUserProfilePicture('', detailedData.id)` provide something wrong parameters and generate error in the function so that it goes inside catch statement

Comment: What does `getUserProfilePicture` return? Are you the one implementing the method?

Comment: It's a call to the microsoft graph api, it either returns: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/63c31121-cd15-4f48-ba43-8dea613f19cd/photo/$value 404 (Not Found) when unseccesful or : 
succesful callblob:http://localhost:8480/7da29a36-d13d-440f-8207-75f1cde58fcf when successful, i updated my post a little.

Comment: In your latter code, the new promise is always resolved. You need to reject it in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
.then(function success(photo) {
    console.log("succesful call" + photo);
}, function(err){
    console.log("error" + err);
})
```

?

Answer (score 0):

> The success statement works, however the fail method doesn't.

`.getUserProfilePicture` returns a promise. A promise either succeeds (resolved) or fails (rejected). If `getUserProfilePicture` resolves even by passing invalid data then it has bugs. Your posted code has no problem regarding handling promises' different states.

If you want to reject the promise manually you can throw an error in your success handler:

```
datacontext.graph.getUserProfilePicture('', detailedData.id)
.then(function success(photo) {
    console.log("succesful call" + photo);
    throw new Error('I am an error!');
})
.catch(function error(err) {
    console.log("error" + err);
});
```

Comment: this would make the success throw an error, not really the pathway I was looking for but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @RodneyWormsbecher Well, right, that error actually doesn't make sense, just an example. You should actually fix the code that always returns resolved promise! Try with replacing `console.log(error);` with `deferred.reject(error)` in your `getUserPic` function! I've found a relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282577/when-to-use-deferred-reject